# How to generate entity classes using JPA project along with foreign key names that are actually mentioned in the database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I am using JPA project in eclipse. I usually right click on the project and use JPA Tools -> Generate Entities from tables for generating entity classes.

I am using MySQL and JPA v2.1

But the generated entity class does not contain the foreign key name that I actually mentioned in the database. So this results in duplicate foreign keys (the one created by me and the one that hibernate creates) when I run the project.

Below is the code snipped that I expect the JPA project to create.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="state_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_State_StateId_State_Id"))
private State state;
```

Below is the code snipped that the JPA project actually creates:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="state_id")
private State state;
```

So I need **foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_State_StateId_State_Id"))** also to be created automatically using the JPA project. Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to do reverse engineering using [JDBC configuration with Hibernate Tools(tm)](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e4485)?

Comment: Actually no and I am not aware of. Can you point to me a suitable link for it?

Comment: I already did above -.-